# Why does Visual Studio 2015 blur all the lines in the text-editor together?

Tags: visual-studio

For the past two weeks, I have been experiencing some very strange behavior with Visual Studio 2015 Professional. I will be writing code when all of a sudden multiple different lines will become blurred together. I have a photograph of what it looks like when this happens shown below:

[image: Visual Studio 2015 Professional text editor]

Once this happens it does not stop. I have tried the following to fix the problem:

- Closing/re-opening Visual Studio 2015 but that does not fix the problem.
- Rebooting my PC, but again that does not fix the problem.
- I have tried the "repair" option from the Visual Studio installer, and that did not make any difference whatsoever.

I have notice that doing some of the following occasionally makes the problem go away temporarily.

- Deleting the `.vs` folder from the project directory. However even after deleting the `.vs` folder, the problem resurfaces within a day.
- Occasionally just doing a *clean solution* will do the trick and make the problem go away for a while...

As one of the comments suggested, I thought about what I had added on to Visual Studio since the problem started occuring. I've realized that one of those things is *Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects*. After removing/re-adding the `.vdproj` installer project from my solution, the problem went away. At this point I am not sure whether or not it will come back. I will wait a while and then provide an update.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here? This is seriously interrupting my work.

**Updates**

The installer project had nothing to do with this problem, and just doing a *clean* seems to be the most effective at making the problem go away.

I looked into disabling the hardware acceleration, but do not have sufficient rights here on this computer. So this will not be an option for me.

Ok, so after disabling the hardware acceleration feature within Visual Studio, the problem immediately showed up after closing/re-opening the solution.

Although I do not know how to fix this problem, I think that I see what is causing it. Inside of my WPF project solution, I have my `MainWindow.xaml` file open in one window and my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file open in another. When I click on one of the elements inside of the `MainWindow.xaml` file and then use my mouse to scroll on `MainWindow.xaml.cs` (without first giving focus/clicking) then problem occurs. Once I click on the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` text-editor window, the problem seems to go away. This is how I've been able to recreate the problem, hopes this helps figure out what is going on here. Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

This doesn't just happen in WPF anymore, but in any project.

Comment: Have you got any code-enhancement add-ons (colorizers, spell checker, etc.) installed? If so, does disabling them help any?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I did add the VS installers 2015 extension. It was never happening before this, but I want to say that this likely has nothing to do with the problem for the following reason. After installing the VS-installers package, I worked for about 7-weeks straight with no issues at all. Just about two weeks ago this started happening.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Not sure if you are familiar with that package, but it just allows me to add installer projects to my solution. I guess I could try removing the installer project and see if the problem goes away. I may give that a try once the problem comes back.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 See my update.

Comment: Did you try disabling hardware acceleration yet? It might help.

Comment: @DanielB Disabling hardware acceleration? No I have not tried that, thanks for the advice. I will look into it, and provide another update.

Comment: @DanielB Unfortunately I do not have the privilege of changing the display settings on this computer so I cannot disable hardware acceleration.

Comment: I’m not talking about the computer but Visual Studio.

Comment: @DanielB Oh? Didn't know there was such a thing. Thank you again that sounds rather promising. I'll have another look into this.

Comment: @DanielB Unfortunately disabling the hardware acceleration inside of Visual Studio did not fix the problem, but thanks for the advice. I have added this to my list of updates.

Comment: Did you try just highlighting/selecting the code by CTRL+A? This happens to me every once in a while in any random programme and it seems to be just some silly issue with graphics refresh not occurring. The selection/highligting of the text seems to force the refresh and un-eff up the lines merging.

Comment: @Eleshar although it does not sound like this will fix the problem permanently that sounds very promising, I will give that a try.

Comment: @Eleshar I gotta say... While *Ctrl+A* doesn't fix the problem permanently, it does make it go away for quite a while! I will just keep doing this for now until a permanent solution is determined. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped - reposting comment as reply.

Answer (score 1):

Following the comment above - the issue seems to be with the text graphics not refreshing correctly and leaving ghosts/artifacts that are scrollable and everything (typically, I have this problem most frequently in Word but sometimes also even in web browsers - basically anything working with large amounts of text lines).

I don't know the permanent solution but a momentary work-around for that is to force it to refresh, which can be done e.g. by highlighting it (best way is CTRL+A). The lines will then unmerge and appear in their correct positions.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and it was driving me crazy...

I'm happy to report that I have *just* found an effective means to solve this issue!

Problem: I had some tools/widgets docked to the sides of the code editor. Something must have gotten corrupted, or set wrong, in my configuration files.

Fix: I docked all tools/widgets to the bottom of the screen. After doing that, the code editor now scrolls properly.

Thankfully, I was able to re-dock my tools/widgets to my preferred locations and the scrolling issue did *NOT* come back.

Comment: I can reliably reproduce this issue in fact: my preferred layout always generates the scrolling issue. However, I can make a slight alteration to give me a very acceptable layout that does *not* break the scrolling.